# What verb to use before "blood test"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am struggling to find a good verb to fill the blank below:

> This year I got into the habit of ___ blood tests regularly.

I thought about "doing", though I don't like how it sounds. Rewriting the expression to "getting blood tested" also crossed my mind, but I would prefer not to use "get" twice.

A compound phrase would be acceptable.

Comment: I'm not sure that 'habit' fits with blood tests. Perhaps '... into the established routine of having ...'. And 'going for' would be commonly heard (assuming a journey was involved).

Comment: Thanks Edwin, I haven't considered "routine" and "going for".

Comment: @High Performance Mark, that would put too much emphasis on "blood". The point in more general: just getting tested regularly (but without the "blood" prefix the phrase is vague).

Comment: 'getting blood tests' is the de facto phrase.  Consider a different word/phrase for the first 'got'.  For example, This year I developed a habit of getting routine blood tests.

Comment: You had more than one blood test in a year? Multiple tests? "getting or having regular blood tests". Good old getting and having.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger thanks Jason, that's good to know. I didn't know that that was the de facto phrase. I would mark your observation as the accepted answer if you repost it below.

Answer (score 2):

You can say "This year, I got into the habit of having my blood tested regularly."

Comment: Of course. And if the poster is not a native speaker, one should emphasize that in English we often lack specific verbs in certain phrases where they exist in, say, German.